# Accessing cached data in RTK Query(new)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Imagine we have 3 component.
first is index which is parent.
second is filter component and third one is table component.
I used mutations for filter some data and show them in table.
In filter component I did this:

```
  const [filterSomeData] = useFilterSomeDataMutation();
  const data = filterSomeData(myFilter);
```

Now I need to access **data** in table component.
Redux toolkit query with every request cache the result , how can I access that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally: If you are receiving data from the server without triggering a change on the server, you should be using a query, not a mutation. Yes, you can do POST requests with Queries and the syntax is 100% the same as with mutations.

Then you should be using that `useQuery` hook in all components that need that data, with the same argument as you passed in initially. That means if you have something like a filter, that you should either pass that filter in by props (by lifting the filter state up to a common parent) or keeping that filter in a Redux slice and getting it from Redux before calling your query hook.

Since you are calling that `useQuery` hook with the same argument in multiple components, it will not make multiple requests, but reuse the response of the first request.

Comment: thank you for your answer that was helpful ,
by the way is there any way to do not call useQuery hook in another component?
maybe something like fixedCacheKey or accessing cached data with requestId?

Comment: No. Cached data is indexed with the arguments it was called with. And if any of those arguments changes, a new independent cache entry is going to be created.

Comment: And what about mutations.how to access the data returned from a mutation in a different component.

Comment: @phry please check this question too https://stackoverflow.com/q/75567002/13789135

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `api.endpoints.foo.useLazyQuery()` or `api.useLazyFooQuery()`. This way you can assess the last fetched data on that endpoint.
Read more from the official doc: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#usequerystate

Answer (score 0):

As in RTK documentation is explained, the proposed solution is calling `useQuery` hooks with the same arguments as before it called. It retrieves data from cached enpoints, But as I need too many arguments to send to query hook, and I should send it to other component, so I prefer to use the `store` object to access data from endpoints as below:

```
    const store = useStore();
    const cachedQueries = store.getState().dashboardApi.queries;
```

Then I made an object with endpoint's name as key and their `data` as value:

```
    let dashboardResult: { [key: string]: any } = {};        
    Object.values(cachedQueries).forEach((item: any) => {
        dashboardResult = { 
           ...dashboardResult,
           ...{ [item?.endpointName]: item?.data?.data }
        }
    });
```