# access RTK-query data in createSlice action

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

what woud be the correct way to access RTK-query data inside createSlice reducers?

Like, for example 'select all' functionality in the code below.

is it possible to access current `useGetOrdersQuery()` data inside `toggleSelectAll()` action?

or the only/best way to implement 'select/deselect all' would be to pass `useGetOrdersQuery()` data to `toggleSelectAll()` action as action payload?

**dashboardSlice.js**

```js
const initialState = {
  selectedIds: [],
};
export const dashboardSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'dashboard',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    toggleSelectAll: (state, action) => {
       //get "useGetOrdersQuery" data id's and assign to state.selectedIds
    }
  }
});

export const { toggleSelectAll } = dashboardSlice.actions;
export const selectSelectedIds = state => state.dashboard.selectedIds;
```

**orders-lsit.js**

```js
import { useGetOrdersQuery } from './api'
import { toggleSelectAll, selectSelectedIds } from './dashboardSlice';

const OrdersList = () => {
  const {data} = useGetOrdersQuery(123);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const selectedIds = useSelector(selectSelectedIds);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(toggleSelectAll())}>
        select/deselect all
      </button>
      {data.map(o => (
        <div>
          <h2>{o.name}</h2>
          <input 
            type="checkbox"
            checked={selectedIds.includes(o.id)}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**api.js**

```js
export const api = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/api' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getOrders: builder.query({
      query: (userId) => `${userId}/orders`,
      providesTags: [{ type: 'Orders', id: 'LIST' }]
    })
  })
});

export const { useGetOrdersQuery } = api;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to save the ids you can do this :

```
const initialState = {
  selectedIds: [],
};
export const dashboardSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'dashboard',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    toggleSelectAll: (state, action) => {
       //get "useGetOrdersQuery" data id's and assign to state.selectedIds
       const { ids }  = action.payload;
       state.selectedIds = ids;
       return state;
    }
  }
});

export const { toggleSelectAll } = dashboardSlice.actions;
export const selectSelectedIds = state => state.dashboard.selectedIds;
```

and

```
import { useGetOrdersQuery } from './api'
import { toggleSelectAll, selectSelectedIds } from './dashboardSlice';

const OrdersList = () => {
  const {data} = useGetOrdersQuery(123);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const selectedIds = useSelector(selectSelectedIds);


  // you can pass the list of ids as a payload to your action and store it for later use.
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(toggleSelectAll({ids: data.map(item => item.id}))}>
        select/deselect all
      </button>
      {data.map(o => (
        <div>
          <h2>{o.name}</h2>
          <input 
            type="checkbox"
            checked={selectedIds.includes(o.id)}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

you have something like this too:
check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71393010/accessing-cached-data-in-rtk-querynew)

```
const store = useStore();
const allDataOfAllQueries = store.getState().api.queries;
console.log(Object.values(allDataOfAllQueries);
```