# How to access, update and delete cached data in RTK query?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

So I am using RTK query in my app and I have used it in multiple apps before (and it seems easy and saves a lot of time). But I have a question regarding authentication.

So how I have been handling authentication is I created a separate slice to store the user details, so I called the mutation for logging a user in (or registering a user) created using RTK query, then getting back the response and dispatching the action to store the data in the other slice created for the data, so that I can access the data in any screen (like token, username etc).

But as the RTK query saves the response in cache too (if i am not wrong), it seems a bit wrong to me to create a different slice to store some data which is already getting stored automatically.

So I wanted to know if there is a way to access the cache directly and do other operations on that like deleting the cache completely (if user logs out), update the cache (e.g, if token refreshes, or user changes the username or any other update).

One more thing, this data (i.e, user specific data like token, username, email etc) is not only returned after logging in but nearly the same data is returned if the user registers or resets the password (in password reset, I am logging the user directly in without letting him to manually do that after reseting the password).

In that case, I want to have a single cache object or document to have the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the docs, I found the answer. To share the data between mutations, we can use `fixedCacheKey: "logindata"` in all the mutations to name the cache as `logindata` (can be named whatever we want).

E.g, if i have two mutations, `login` and `register`, and we want them to have the same cache key, we can do so by;

```
const [login, {isLoading}] = useLoginMutation({fixedCacheKey: "logindata"})


const [login, {isLoading}] = useRegisterMutation({fixedCacheKey: "logindata"})
```

I think we can access the data too using useSelector now as the key is not changing now and is fixed to `logindata` (not tried yet).

Now I am just struggling with clearing the whole cache including the cache of mutations too.

**EDIT**:

we can clear the whole cache by using `api.util.resetApiState()`. I just forgot to dispatch it, so it was not working.

`dispatch(api.util.resetApiState())`, clears the whole cache (usually can be used on logout).

Now the last step remaining, update the cache of one mutation from other mutation (not replacing completely, but just updating one property).

**Edit**:

I had to change the structure as per [this](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter#crud-functions)